# Induced current in an infinite plate

Tags: electromagnetism

**Question**: An infinite wire carries a constant current . Now an infinite plate is brought into the system from infinity, and placed on the left side of the wire, such that the plate is parallell to the wire. What is the new magnetic field?

**Attempt at answer**: I had no clue how to solve this question. I think that there’s an induced current in the infinite plate in the opposite direction, in order to cancel the flux. However, I always ran into problems because the plate is infinite, and the induced current can’t be infinite. Any help or tips are appreciated.

Comment: The infinite plate won't affect the magnetic field in any way, assuming it's uncharged. The infinite wire is the only contributing factor to any electromagnetic fields in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While moving the superconducting plate into the direction of the wire the magentic field exertes a redistributional force onto the charge distribution, that cancels the magnetic field left to the superconducting plate exactly. For not to run into topological complications of currents, take a wire inside a torus and look at it locally.

If the surface is not superconducting, the redistribution of the moving wire relaxes fast and the magnetic field everywhere is inaffected after the wire is halted.

Answer (score 0):

The normal component of the magnetic field at a conductor is zero.
This means that the magnetic field has to be modified. The problem can probably be solved by introducing an image current, similar to the image charges used for electric fields.

Comment: What does this mean for the magnetic field to te left of the plate? Because then you can’t use this method anymore, right?

Comment: I am aware that the image current is not really there, but I am also interested in the magnetic field to the left of the infite plate (the wire is on the right. As far as I understand it, you can’t use the method of image currents in that case. So how do I get the magnetic field in that region?

Comment: Oops.  My answer was for an oscillating current, which is what I usually work with. For a steady current the magnetic field would be unchanged inside the conductor, just as in uriyabsc's comment